# MySQL query parameters in a Pentaho CE dashboard

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-cde

First, I'm on **Pentaho CE 8.0.** And I'm not an expert on **Pentaho**.

The question seems simple but I cannot get it working. I'm trying for a dashboard to use a simple parameter for a WHERE condition in a **MySQL query**. The Bootstrap layout has 3 columns, one for each component (filter, text, table).

**Simple parameter:**

```
- Name: salesrep_selection  
- Property value: mike
```

**Filter component (to select the sales rep):**

```
- Name: salesrep_selection_filter  
- Parameter: salesrep_selection  
- Values Array: [["mike","Mike"],["paul","Paul"],["peter","Peter"]]  
- Value as Id: false
```

**Text component: (just to check that the parameter is set up):**

```
- Name: selection_show_text  
- Listeners: ["salesrep_selection"]  
- Expression: function() {return this.dashboard.getParameterValue("salesrep_selection");}
```

**Table component (customers list by sales rep):**

```
- Name: customers_list_table  
- Listeners: ["salesrep_selection"]  
- Datasource: customers_list_data
```

**Datasource (MySQL query):**

```
- Name: companies_list_data  
- Jndi: business_datawarehouse  
- Query: SELECT customerid,customername FROM customers WHERE salesrep=${salesrep_selection}  
- Parameters: [] (empty)
```

When I start the dashboard, I get my selection list with the sales reps names. When I choose one, the id is displayed in the text component, but the table remains empty "No data available in table".

If I hard code the condition `"WHERE salesrep='mike'"`, I get the list of customers.

With the parameter `"WHERE salesrep=${salesrep_selection}"`, the MySQL query log shows me that it gets `"WHERE salesrep=null"`. So the parameter is not sent to the query.

I also tried to set up the datasource parameters with `[["salesrep_selection","salesrep_selection"]],` but the table remains empty "No data available in table", and the MySQL query log shows `"WHERE salesrep='salesrep_selection'".`

I searched a lot on internet, not a lot of articles about this, but anyway, what I found is exactly what I implemented. And still I don't get anything working.

Are the parameters handled differently in Pentaho CE 8.0? The queries parameters too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass parameter from component to datasource.

1. Add parameter called `salesrep_selection` with value `salesrep_selection` to Table component's property `Parameters`. This will set up the parameter in the component and it will pass its value to the datasource.
2. Add the same parameter in the Datasource's property `Parameters`. This will set up the parameter in the datasource and it will pass its value to the query.

**Table component (customers list by sales rep):**

```
- Name: customers_list_table  
- Listeners: ["salesrep_selection"]  
- Datasource: customers_list_data  
- Parameters: [["salesrep_selection", "salesrep_selection"]]
```

**Datasource (MySQL query):**

```
- Name: companies_list_data  
- Jndi: business_datawarehouse  
- Query: SELECT customerid,customername FROM customers WHERE salesrep=${salesrep_selection}  
- Parameters: [["salesrep_selection", "salesrep_selection"]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mzy! I tried with the parameters in the datasource, but I didn't try with declaring the parameters again inside the calling component (here **Table component**).