# parameters on query and their necessary components

Tags: sql, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I'm too newbie and alone at the office with Pentaho CDE tool and I freeze with the design of my "easy" dashboard since several days ago... I have a sql query where I need to use a parameter to input a date:

```
select uc_descr, semana, count(*) n_anotaciones
from base_table
where semana >= to_date(${IntroduceFecha}, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by uc_descr, semana
order by semana ,uc_descr
```

It worked with a fixed value ('31-01-2018') instead the `${IntroduceFecha}` and returns me a table with the right rows, but I'm not able to make it works with the parameter. I used 3 objects on the components panel:

- table component to show the rows content
- date parameter, to define the parameter
- date input component, to receive the user's date definition

The layout worked fine...and I think data source too.

Please can give anybody a tip or an advice about what I'm doing bad...I have tried with simple parameter instead the date one, and with text input instead the date input as well (modifying the query, of course). But I don't find a solution.

Comment: I don't know pentaho, but my guess is that you are constructing a string with the select statement and pass it on for execution. If this is the case, you can have your program deploying the correct date during the string construction process. A second solution would be to use parameters passing, but it would be far more complex.

Comment: Thanks FDavidov! as you comment the mainly problem is to manage dates and their formats between SQL queries and Pentaho components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question and answer could help you with setting up parameters in `Table Component` and passing them to `SQL Datasource`.

- [MySQL query parameters in a Pentaho CE dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442460/mysql-query-parameters-in-a-pentaho-ce-dashboard)

Your `Date input component` should set up `date parameter`. `Table Component` should set listener on that parameter a should set it in parameters. `SQL Datasource` should set same parameter as `Table Component` has. And than it can be used in query.

Comment: Thanks a lot mzy, I have checked on last week the same post as you refers, but I couldn't understand it completely. Finally I solved it by myself but right now, I will try it with your expert tips. I used a simple parameter (instead  a date one) and with text input component (instead the date input component). As you say it's just to master clearly 3 concepts parameter, parameters and listeners...First one; receive the variable, second one; values neccesaries to complete the action on the component, the last one;when the parameter changes update the component.